# Program to return power of 2 without using any power function

Tags: java

I want a program that takes an `int x` as parameter and returns `2^x`. The implementation is not allowed to use power of.

```
public int double2 (int x) {
    int r = 2;
    int y = 1;
    for (int i=0; i < x; i++){    
        y = r* y;
    }
    return y;
}
```

Do you think this is a right solution?

Comment: You should explain this more clearly, what are you trying to do? (sounds like homework)

Comment: "The double of 2"? Do you mean 4?

Comment: return 2; // 2's doppleganger

Comment: yes it is a homework >>> but the teacher explain nothing >>
i mean that i want the result of 2^2, 2^3 , 2^4 and so on without the power >> i have to use anothe formula

Comment: That is commonly referred to as "power of 2", "double of 2" would be just 4.

With respect to it being the right solution, does it give you the answer you expect? r is loop invariant, and need not be a variable at all. There is a simpler solution.

Comment: Inexplicably closed IMO (while I was entering a response). It may be a badly articulated question from a non-mathematician, but why is it "not a real question"? The simpler solution for what it is worth is 2^n as a C expression is simply 1 << n - its a binary computer - powers of two are how it works!

Comment: Do you really mean 2^<input>?  e.g. passing in 5 will give you 2^5 to return 32?  or the other way round passing in 5 gives 5^2 to return 25?

Comment: the teacher explained *everything*

Comment: @ ss: Please, try to improve your language. Sentences start with uppercase letters. Use ".", ",", "-" or ";" to structure your sentences, *NOT* ">>", which is not a valid punctuation in English, but *is* a valid arithmetic operand in the *other* language referenced in your question (Java). Not few of the people visiting this site (including me) are not native speakers, and they have a hard time figuring out sentences like yours. Clear language *is* a core skill for a software developer.

Comment: @abelenky: The system automatically made it a CW, after 7 different users edited it.

Answer (score 5):

The solution you posted using the for loop produces the right result, but you should look into a more efficient solution ([bit shifting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Arithmetic_shift)) as Adamski first mentioned.

Comment: This is the best answer, not only because bit shifting is absolutely the right thing to use here, but because this answer doesn't do the OP's homework for him.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
int power = someNumberHere;
int result = 1;
while (power-- > 0) result *= 2;
```

And I think that is what you want...I think. Are you trying to find a power of two? Maybe expand the question, scope and reasons behind what you want a little.

Comment: yes, it can be done like that but how is the compltion >>>> what if I put for loop instead of while??

Comment: So what does *power* do in this? I think you want "while (power-- > 0) *= 2"

Comment: It is far more efficient to do a single bit shift operation than to multiple by 2 several times in a loop.

Comment: But stupid people chose to close the question for no good reason, so he may never know.

Answer (score 0):

```
y = x*x;
```

or

```
y = x*2;
```

or

```
y = 42; // ;)
```

Depending in what do you mean by the "double of 2".

**EDIT**

naive implementation

```
public int 2powerOf( int n ) {
    int r = 2;
    for( int i = 1 ; i < n ; i++ ) {
        r = r * 2;
    }
    return r;
 }
```

It is almost as the one you posted, this might not handle negative values though.

If you want to know if yours works, then run it and find out for your self.

Comment: i mean 2^2 2^3 2^4 

but the power i will add it as veriable

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if you need such kind of explanatory code (it's in C though).

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int base, power, index;
    long answer;
    base = 0;
    power = 0;
    answer = 1.00;

    printf(" Enter a base number: ");
    scanf("%d", &base);
    printf(" Enter a power to raise the base to: ");
    scanf("%d", &power);

    for(index = 1; index <= power; index++)
        answer = answer * base;

    printf("%d raised to the power of %d is %ld.", base, power, answer);
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Does your implementation passes the following JUnit test?

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class YourClassTest extends TestCase {

    private YourClass sut = new YourClass();

    public void testPowersOfTwo() {
        assertEquals(1, sut.double2(0));
        assertEquals(2, sut.double2(1));
        assertEquals(4, sut.double2(2));
        assertEquals(8, sut.double2(3));
        assertEquals(16, sut.double2(4));
    }

}
```

If it does, it is a working solution (but maybe not optimal).